# Google Chrome: map PID to window

Tags: google-chrome

I see in `ps` that one of my Google Chrome renderers is taking an unexpectedly large percentage of CPU.

How can I determine which Chrome window is being rendered by that process?

note: my primary environments are Linux and MacOS, in case there's not a cross-platform answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to bring up the Chrome Task Manager ("Window/Task Manager", choose the "View Background Pages" option) and opt to display the "Process ID" column (right-click on the column header, and choose "Process ID" from the menu that comes up). It works on Windows, and I'd imagine it would work on Linux and MacOS.

Of course, once you're in the Chrome Task Manager, you can see CPU usage for each tab (aka process) there already, so there's no need for the process ID->window mapping.